# Unity3d: Version2018.2 TouchInputModule obsolete

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, obsolete

I am recently working on a project and I need to create custom events for different input methods/devices.
Since the latest Unity update the Input.Touch method is not working anymore. Right now i am not able to find a method to get a touch input, that is that easy to use as `Input.GetTouch` (etc)...

I dont know what i am not seeing here. I feel like there must be a very easy way to get the count and position of fingers touching the display. I spent today failing on recieving a data set that I got with the 2018.1 Version using one line of code.

If someone could show me a solution for this problem I would be very grateful!

Comment: Temporary solution:
I finally solved this super annoying problem. 
edit> Project Settings> Input> Active Input Handling> (was "both") set to: "Input Manager"

Since my project is a group project and we use a lot of plugins and assets from older projects i could not find the script or setting or whatsoever that was causing that unity could not get any input via touch. But... setting off the new input system worked for me for now. Now i have to find the bug in my project but maybe that temp solution helps somebody else as well...

Best,
Chrsitian.